# checkbox appears dynamic in php

Tags: php, html

Here is my piece of code:

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT denumire_intrebare,denumire_varianta,tip_intrebare 
                FROM intrebari,variante 
                WHERE intrebari.cod_chestionar='".$_SESSION['cod']."' 
                AND intrebari.cod_intrebare=variante.cod_intrebare");

while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))    
if($b['tip_intrebare']==3)    
{    
echo $b['denumire_intrebare'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='option1' value='Milk'>";
echo $b['denumire_varianta'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

So let me explain. I query the database and it brings me up a question and the answers that are related to it. I want the answers to put them as checkbox answers. The problem is that my question is repeating for all the answers. So if i have 5 answers then the question appears 5 times like this: question answer1, question answer2, ... . I want my question to appear only once with the answers under the question. I'm missing something but I don't know what. Any help?

Comment: **TIP:** wrap `while` statement with  `{`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array with all `$b['denumire_varianta']` and use a `foreach()` after the while has finished, also make your checkboxes array so you can get them afterwards:

```
$variante = array();
while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
    if($b['tip_intrebare']==3){
        $intrebare = $b['denumire_intrebare'];
        $variante[] = $b['denumire_varianta'];
    }
}
echo $intrebare."<br />";
foreach($variante as $varianta){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='".$varianta."'>";
    echo $varianta."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Please use English here, and sorry my time is limited, you can find my email address if you look.